# difference between standalone Expo app and expo go

Tags: react-native, expo, google-authentication, expo-go

I want to implement google sign in expo app.
But while reading doc, it says expo-google-sign-in cannot be used in Expo Go. but it only works for standalone Expo apps
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/google-sign-in/#usage-with-firebase
I don't understand what this means.

I have created expo app using `expo init` command.
Is this standalone app or Expo go?

Please let me clear about this.

Answer (score 7):

**Wild guess here** :

Expo Go is an app where you can test your app in it (when you scan the QR Code after `expo start`, your app is launched inside Expo Go app).
Standalone Expo app is your application when you upload it on the store.

I had the same issue for notifications : inside Expo Go app, notifications didn't work for my app but when I uploaded my app on the AppStore, notifications worked fine.

Comment: then  expo-google-sign-in will not work when expo app uploaded to appstore?

Comment: expo-google-sign-in will work in your app on the app store but it will not work in the Expo Go app